# Filter data range JavaScript

Tags: javascript, date, onchange

I have a list that needs to be filtered between two dates.

I am using the following code:

```
var flagDateTime = '@flagDate';

$('#CreateDateStart, #CreateDateEnd').on('dp.change', function () {
    if (flagDateTime === 'False') { 
        flagDateTime = true; 
    }
    else {
        $("#preFilter").click()
    }
});
```

I'm declaring a variable, `flagDateTime`, and then doing the validation, but when I change the dates again my variable sets to `False` again. I just want it to be `false` one time, then it must be always `true`.

How can I do that?

Comment: Your code is not filtering anything, it just sets either a variable to `true` or triggers a `click` of an element that you have not included in your question. How can we help you?

Comment: Resolved using oldVal property

Comment: This question is completely useless. There is no mention of `oldVal`.